# how is pandas rolling average calculated?

Tags: python, pandas

Hopefully this isn't a silly question...but I have a project that logs data every approximately every second into a pandas df for a few columns of numeric sensor values and also a time stamp column. A project requirement is taking in data on a 5 minute rolling average, running some fault checks, and then clearing the data frame.

If I am clearing the data every 5 minutes (basically only using Pandas for the rolling avg feature) after the fault check would I still need this:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df = df.set_index("timestamp")
df = df.rolling("5T").mean()
```

Or for my columns could I just take a column mean instead of the last 5 minutes of data?

```
for col in df.columns:
    print(f"df column: {col} - {df[col].mean()}")
```

Now I am rethinking what a 5 minute rolling average would be on 5 minutes of data. What I think that is but could be wrong a 5 minute rolling average on 5 minutes of data would boil the dataframe down to a single row of data representing the previous 5 minute mean values.

Any tips appreciated! Maybe Panda isnt a good application for this and just using a list would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) instead to group the data into non-overlapping five-minute intervals, and the mean() method is used to calculate the mean of each column within each interval.

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df = df.set_index("timestamp")
mean_df = df.resample('5T').mean()
```